# Bootstrap - 4 Tables side by side and responsive

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have 4 responsive tables (with bootstrap) side by side?
Like so:
[image]

I want the headings of each table to be fixed when I scroll through.

Don't know how to do it.

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: Have you achieved fixing the headers for one table? I would start there and then use some sort of flex or grid to display them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have:

```
<html> 
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<h2 class="sub-header">Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
          <h2 class="sub-header">Latest Incidents</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<h2 class="sub-header">Subtitle</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
          <h2 class="sub-header">Latest Incidents</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-md-1">#</th>
                  <th class="col-md-2">Header</th>
                  <th class="col-md-3">Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td class="col-md-1">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-2">1,001</td>
                  <td class="col-md-3">1,001</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```